# Better way of processing multiple form fields

Tags: php, html, forms

Is there  a better way to process a form where I need to save a `link` and `link text` against a language and company?

The example below works, but I think it is hard work.

I have added the language and company id to the key of the link and link text fields as a way of grouping them together and passing the other information through to PHP and into the DB.

```
$newlinks = array();
foreach($_POST as $post_key => $post_value) {
  if (substr($post_key, 0, 7) == 'newlink') {
    $posted_link = explode('_', $post_key);
    $newlinks[$posted_link[1]][$posted_link[2]][$posted_link[0]] = $post_value;
    $newlinks[$posted_link[1]][$posted_link[2]]['language_id'] = $posted_link[1];
    $newlinks[$posted_link[1]][$posted_link[2]]['company_id'] = $posted_link[2];

  }
}

foreach($newlinks as $newlinklang) {
  foreach($newlinklang as $newlink) {
    if ($newlink['newlink'] != '' && $newlink['newlinkname'] != '') {
      $sql = "
        INSERT
          INTO
        ".$db_prefix."catalogue_links (
          link,
          link_name,
          language_id,
          company_id
        ) VALUES (
          '".$newlink['newlink']."',
          '".$newlink['newlinkname']."',
          '".$newlink['language_id']."',
          '".$newlink['company_id']."'
        ";
    }
  }
}
```

And the HTML

```
<input type="text" name="newlink_1_1" value="" />
<input type="text" name="newlinkname_1_1" value="" />
```

There can be multiple languages and companies displayed on one page.

Comment: As a side note, please be sure to sanitize those inputs!  Your SQL statement is making me cringe.  Use http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php or use prepared statements.

Comment: Thanks @nategood, simplifying the code for SO i removed my cleaning from the post key and values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `something[]` as the field name. Then PHP will create an array in `$_POST['something']` (or $_GET, and $_REQUEST - obviously) which you can use without ugly substring comparisons.

You could also specify array indexes in the field name (`name="something[42]"`). This might be a good idea if you have multiple fields which belong together. While the order is supposed to be correct anyway (so you can `foreach($_POST['field1'] as $idx => $val)` and use `_POST['field2'][$idx]`) it might be safer or at least more intuitive for someone reading the code if the indexes are also in the HTML code.

Comment: Thanks, html arrays look like the best approach, but looks like there will be lots of looping to format the arrays to have the language and company at the same level as the details. Thanks